# How can I compute this value?

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform

I want to calculate

$$ \int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} e^{-i\lambda \theta \cdot x} d \theta $$

where $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is unit sphere, $\lambda \in (0,\infty)$, and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Is this possible to write down this value in the elementary functions? (or with some special function?)

Comment: By a simple parameterization of $\mathbb{S}^{n-2}$ it boils down to 
$$\int_0^\pi \sin^{n-2}\phi \, e^{-i|\lambda x|\cos\phi} \, d\phi.$$